# Performing transformations on Arrow table

Tags: bigdata, pyarrow, apache-arrow

What kind of transformations can you apply to an Arrow table?

Is its main use (for now) an interchange format for languages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now, not much, but in 2019 the [roadmap](https://docs.google.com/document/d/12dWBniKW2JQ-5djE3SPjyQXVquCAEmLXVlb1dnhLhQ0/edit?usp=sharing) contains building a computational engine which aims to support most of data operations (filter, aggregatations, join, etc...).